# Handling Typos and Soundex conditions While Searching a String in Java without Interacting Database

Tags: java, spring, search, lucene, hibernate-search

My Application Uses Hibernate Search to handle all possible Search Criteria. However, there is a need for me to Obtain Collection of Objects from Database and based upon user inputs, need to perform search on obtained collection. My System should able to handle typos and sound-ex conditions too. The manner in which I interact with the database in this condition is only through Hibernate Criteria as only it can serve my purpose and I cannot use Hibernate Search here.

Is there any way where I can use Hibernate Search along with Hibernate Criteria? My requirement is Hibernate search should be done on results obtained from criteria, but not on the DB.  I guess doing it in DAO is not possible and hence thinking of handling it in service layer. Do we have any library similar to Hibernate Search, Apache Lucene to perform search(including Typos and soundex) on Collection of Objects.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, I ll surely learn the best practices as I interact more.. Can you help me in getting a solution to my query